# Get text at top of screen during scroll?

Tags: javascript, viewport, line-numbers

I'm looking for a way for javascript to tell how far a user has scrolled down the screen.

Instead of doing this through x, y coordinates is there a way to pull what's at the top of the viewport?

Either the text / line number or the current top element in the viewport?

Comment: Please do not put tags ("Javascript: ...") in the subject.

Comment: Use plain JavaScript, for example: `var clientrect=document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect();var top=clientrect.top;var left=clientrect.left`. See also: [MDN: element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.
You have to set scroll events and update x and y values.
Then, with those values, you can get the element at this position.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536417%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuerys [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

This should probably do it for you:

```
$("body").scrollTop()
```